# Using a converter for more than one binding?

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to do something like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Binding}">
    <Setter Property="Converter" Value="{StaticResource converter1}"/>
</Style>
```

That doesn't work though. So how do I tell more than one binding which converter to use without writing it explicitly for every single one?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. What does not work? What did you expect? What happened?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to say, but there are actually two reasons you cannot do this.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Binding}">
    <Setter Property="Converter" Value="{StaticResource converter1}"/>
</Style>
```

Firstly, you cannot create a style for `System.Windows.Data.Binding` because it does not meet the requirements for styling. The [`TargetType` must derive from either `FrameworkElement` or `FrameworkContentElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.targettype(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1). Alas, [`Binding` inherits](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_0) from `BindingBase`, then `MarkupExtension`, then `Object` and so it cannot be styled.

Secondly, [`Setter.Property` is of type `DependencyProperty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.setter.property(v=vs.110).aspx). [`Binding.Converter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter(v=vs.110).aspx) is not a dependency property, so it simply cannot have a value bound to it.

*So*, you will have to repeat the `Converer={StaticResource converter1}` within the braces of each XAML `{Binding}` markup extension.